# reset terminal without ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist

Tags: git, shell

I was trying to run PostgreSQL in rails in terminal and ended up using a whole bunch of `sudo` commands... lo and behold, now when I try to run a static project with `$ rails new sample_app --skip-test-unit` i no longer am able to run `git` commands from terminal. I do not receive an error and pressing Ctrl-Z results in a `Stopped` message.

I was looking to see if perhaps there was some 'cache' that I may reset? I noticed threads stating to look for and delete the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` file, however, I cannot find such a file. Thank you in advance. -Ray

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you somehow deleted your .git folder. Use `git init` at the root level and `git remote add origin <url>` to reattach to the remote. You will also have to set up your tracking for your branches. See `--set-upstream` option on the branch command.

**Edit:** Absolutely, I did the following and it worked:

```
$ brew remove git
$ brew install git
$ PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```